# Is there a way to use Raspberry Pi for a pinball machine?

Tags: games

I want to build my own pinball machine. Can Raspberry Pi come handy??

Comment: Hi D.vader, and welcome to SE Raspberry Pi! While this question is upon an interesting, and amusing/entertaining, topic, it is rather terse. Could you edit your question and expand upon it somewhat?  What research have you done so far? What hardware/software have you completed? What issues are you facing? The more detailed the description in your question, the more accurate the answers - and it also makes it more likely that someone will be able to help you... :-)

Comment: @Greenonline I think that he is starting to meet a RPi world, and further details are coming. Right now he needs to know - will it suit his needs? IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a Raspberry Pi could be useful.

Comment: bex you didn't say how

Comment: @D.vader Oh, sorry, but that wasn't part of the question. If you would elaborate your question, you can probably get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Bex - Harsh but fair... lol :-)

Answer (score 2):

Providing you can get all the parts necessary and then hook them up to GPIO pins, I don't see any reason why not. Pinball targets are pretty much all digital so there should be no problem there. Spinners might be analog, but you can add an analog-to-digital converter for that. Look up a few things to do with building arcade machines using the Pi for buttons and other controls. Where you would get the parts to refurb a pinball machine however, I have no idea!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a trick question, but the answer is "Yes".

Here is a lazy google based answer:

- You tube - [My Raspberry Pi Pinball Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9zkO6_6gjM) by [Steven McCulloch](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIeeLk9F2jxCO-L--NOi0jQ), who also has [Controlling Gottleb System 1 Pinball Machine Lamps With Raspberry Pi!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiJt8YJoxcc)
- [Raspberry Pi Pinball Machine](https://pinside.com/pinball/forum/topic/raspberry-pi-pinball-machine) by Bowman9

> This guy is building a pinball machine from scratch using a raspberry pi.

- [Raspberry Pi-Powered Pinball Machine](http://makezine.com/2013/01/16/raspberry-pi-powered-pinball-machine/)

> He hand-built a pinball machine based on the online comedy duo Rhett&Link and controls all the electronics with a Raspberry Pi.

- From Raspberry Pi site itself: [FIREBALL PINBALL HD](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/fireball-pinball-hd/)

> ... Ian Cole, who is refurbishing the pinball machine. He’s been kind enough to prepare a blog post about the project, the educational reasons for starting it with his kids, and a blow-by-blow account of the build, along with a huge number of photographs documenting what he’s been doing.

- And the making of... [The Making of Fireball HD Pinball](http://www.raisinggeeks.com/blog/2013/08/making-fireball-hd-pinball/)

---

Here are some other links: [Search](https://www.google.co.th/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pi%20pinball%20machine)